# Hash Tag not working - Single pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have this wordpress website at http://www.keynote-kommunikation.de/
The website is mainly using paralalax/scroll effect.

Some pages are single pages, like the posts on "News" right after the intro, and the **Imprint** page: http://www.keynote-kommunikation.de/impressum/

On this single pages the **links on the menu** do not work properly. They trigger the main page but do not scroll to the exact point.

Why?

This is the code I use to remove the intro video after the user gets to "News", it's a requirement, I need it, but that's what is causing the issue.

```
//
var startScroll = $('.header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function() {

var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

            if(scrollTop > startScroll) {
                // do something
                $('.header').addClass('header-remove');
                $('.wrap').addClass('wrap-remove');
                $('.inline-menu').addClass('menu-fixed').css('top', adminBar);

                window.scrollTo(0,0);
                startScroll = 22222;
            }

        });
```

Comment: The front screen animation is what causing the issue. Comparing to your website which uses the same theme, http://lopezi.com, the only difference being there is no animation in your site.

Comment: can you please add code

Comment: Scrolling is done properly on ur site.What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that when you are on a single page, ex. http://www.keynote-kommunikation.de/impressum/ and you click the menu links they don't take you to the exact point of the page

Comment: @Jack - I would need some hints on the code, seems it can work

Comment: Lopezi, don't remove the element from the page, it will upset the scroll.

Comment: “Some pages are single pages” — what on earth are the other pages? Conjoined pages?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite He is using wordress term 'single' pages, meaning individual post pages. Here you can think of it as all pages other than homepage.

Comment: @Rao: ahhhhh, gotcha. Cheers cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Check if the url has a #value in it, if yes, then don't allow the front page video animation,

You have the following code which inserts the video,

```
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.video-insert').videoBG({
                mp4:'http://www.keynote-kommunikation.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/KK5x.mp4',
                ogv:'http://www.keynote-kommunikation.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/KK5x.ogv',
                //poster:'http://www.keynote-kommunikation.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/KK5.jpg',
                scale:true,
                zIndex: 1,
                autoplay: true,
        loop: 0,
            });

            ...

        });
        </script>
```

ie., on page load you are inserting the video inside `.video-insert` Now don't run the above code when you have a hash value in the url,

How to check #hash value in url

```
var hval = window.location.hash.slice(1); //TO GET #VAL FROM URL

  if(hval == ''){ 
    //IF NO #VAL, LOAD VIDEO CODE HERE
     ...
  }else{ // WHEN THERE IS A #VAL IN URL
   switch(hval){
     case 'news':
                   $('html, body').animate({
                     scrollTop: $("#news").position().top
                   }, 2000);
                 break;
     case 'somethingelse':
              ...
              ...

  }

}
```

Comment: that works, on my case I had to use the function .position() instead of .offset()